# The libblkid library: what is the 'blkid_superblocks_get_name' function for?

Tags: filesystems, block-device

I'm trying to use the `libblkid` library to analyze various filesystems on a block device from a C/C++ program, and it works well. However I'm confused with the **blkid_superblocks_get_name** function from [this library](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.21/libblkid-docs/libblkid-Superblocks-probing.html#blkid-superblocks-get-name).

The function assigns some `name`, but name of what? Also, what is the meaning of the first (input) argument `idx`? That kind of functions used to have the first argument of type `blkid_probe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a brief look onto the function:

```
int blkid_superblocks_get_name(size_t idx, const char **name, int *usage)
{
    if (idx < ARRAY_SIZE(idinfos)) {
        if (name)
            *name = idinfos[idx]->name;
        if (usage)
            *usage = idinfos[idx]->usage;
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

`name` is a pointer to a `char *` pointer (thus a pointer to a »string«).  The intended use would be something like

```
char *the_name = NULL;
int usage = 0;
size_t idx;

idx = somehow_get_a_valid_index();

blkid_superblock_get_name(idx, &the_name, &usage);
```

The function sets your pointer `the_name` to point to the name of something.  Lets investigate further:  What's `idinfos` and where does it come from?

Turns out `idinfos` is an array of `struct blkid_idinfo *`'s:

```
static const struct blkid_idinfo *idinfos[] =
{
    &aix_pt_idinfo,
    &sgi_pt_idinfo         
    &sun_pt_idinfo,     
    &dos_pt_idinfo,
    &gpt_pt_idinfo,
    &pmbr_pt_idinfo,        /* always after GPT */
    &mac_pt_idinfo,
    &ultrix_pt_idinfo,
    &bsd_pt_idinfo,
    &unixware_pt_idinfo,
    &solaris_x86_pt_idinfo,
    &minix_pt_idinfo
};
```

and looking further we see `struct blkid_idinfo` is

```
struct blkid_idinfo
{
    const char      *name;          /* fs, raid or partition table name */
    int             usage;          /* BLKID_USAGE_* flag */
    int             flags;          /* BLKID_IDINFO_* flags */
    int             minsz;          /* minimal device size */

    int             (*probefunc)(blkid_probe pr, const struct blkid_idmag *mag);
    struct blkid_idmag      magics[];
};
```

Doxygen comment says this describes a filesystem or RAID.  Let's have a look at one of the members of `idinfos`:

```
const struct blkid_idinfo dos_pt_idinfo =
{
    .name           = "dos",
    .probefunc      = probe_dos_pt,
    .magics         =
    {
        /* DOS master boot sector:
         *
         *     0 | Code Area
         *   440 | Optional Disk signature
         *   446 | Partition table
         *   510 | 0x55
         *   511 | 0xAA
         */
        { .magic = "\x55\xAA", .len = 2, .sboff = 510 },
        { NULL }
    }
};
```

This obviously describes the DOS partitioning scheme (a.k.a. MBR partition table).

So `idinfos` describes several recognized partition formats (MBR, GPT, BSD disklabels, …).  Looking back to `blkid_superblocks_getname()` we can see that it takes an `idx`, that is an offset into the `idinfos` array (as quoted above) and makes `name` point to the `name`-element of the corresponding `struct blkid_idinfo` (in the above example `"dos"`).

`libblkid/samples/partitions.c` in the *util-linux* source code shows an example how to use this to iterate supported partition types.

**Note:** the source code of *libblkid* seems to be rather clearly arranged, try having a look at it to understand what it does, it's quite good to understand (`grep` is your friend ;)  Also have a look at the other sample source code to understand how *libblkid* should be used.

Comment: Sorry to say, I don't see any `blkid_superblocks_get_name` calls in the `libblkid/samples/partitions.c` file. My `util-linux` version is 2.20.1 and the `apt-get` says it's the most recent one. However I've found how this function is called in the `blkid` source - it's used to implement option `-k` (list all filesystems the `blkid` understands).

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's `blkid_partitions_get_name` there.  On the other hand, the answer was a bit more explanation than mentioning the examples.

Comment: Anyway, thank you the idea to grep sources of the `util-linux`. I understand now, what the function does.